# Java Combine two list with by removing duplicates

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have two list

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

The list is a list of maps with each map like below

```
name-> XXX
age->yyy
id->zzz
```

Now I want to combine these into a single list and also removing duplicates based on the `id` of the map.

Im using the below to combine the list but not sure how to remove duplicates based on a value of the map

```
List<Map<String,Object>> newList = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create predicates `closure` with `TreeMap` to filter maps with unique `"id"`

```
static Predicate<Map<String, Object>> predicate() {
    var set = new TreeSet<>();
    return m -> set.add(m.get("id")); 
}
```

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> newList = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                .filter(predicate())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simpler using a map to manage unique IDs as keys:

```
// Use LinkedHashMap if order is needed
Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> megaMap = new HashMap<>();
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .forEach(map -> megaMap.computeIfAbsent(map.get("id"), id -> map));

List<Map<String, Object>> newList = new ArrayList<>(megaMap.values());
```

The same map can be generated using `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> megaMap2 = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("id"), 
                                  Function.identity(), 
                                  (v1, v2) -> v1, 
                                  HashMap::new));
newList = new ArrayList<>(megaMap2.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the list then use `Collectors.toMap` to group by map's `id` key and get then map's value in the new ArrayList

```
List<Map<String,Object>> newList = 
   new ArrayList<>(
       Stream.of(list1, list2)
            .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("id"), e -> e, (a, b) -> a)).values());
```